# Motorcycle Engine making a ticking noise after oil change and oil filter swap

Tags: engine, motorcycle, oil-change

I recently changed my bike's oil using the oil specified in the manual, also cleaned out the fuel lines and cleaned the carbs.

Now when I start the bike, I hear this ticking noise, I recorded it in the video below:

https://youtu.be/lS_FB9plQQQ

Is this noise natural? I haven't ridden the bike in a while so maybe I just don't remember the sound. Maybe I just need to let the oil heat up? I'm worried about running it for too long and wasting my engine.

Answer (score 0):

Tightened 3 loose spark plugs and inserted the 4th which was missing. No more ticking.